# Write data to SQL database using python

Tags: python

I want to save information from JSON to my SQL database. However could not write perfectly `cur.execute` statement, where values are coming from the JSON message. Additionally, variable Time is not defined correctly as I do not understand how to combine the current date and 'Time' from JSON message. Could you help to solve these problems?

```
import json
import datetime as dt
import vertica_python
import pandas as pd

#connection to database
conn_info = {'host': '', #'127.0.0.1',
             'port': 3,
             'user': '',
             'password': '',
             'database': '',# 'vdb',
             '': True}
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
cur = connection.cursor()

message = [
              {
                  "ID": 48,
                  "Type": "Update",
                  "UpdateType": "Quote",
                  "Key": {
                      "Service": "Online",
                      "Name": "Audi"
                  },
                  "Fields": {
                      "Buyers": 1000,
                      "Sellers": 500,
                      "Time":"08:34:20.527"
                  }
              }
          ]
data=json.loads(message)

Name = data[0]['Fields']['Name']
Buyers = data[0]['Fields']['Buyers']
Sellers = data[0]['Fields']['Sellers']
Time = dt.combine(dt.date.today(),  dt.strptime(data[0]['Fields']['Time'],'%H:%M:%S')   


cur.execute("INSERT INTO MYdb (CurrentTime, InpuTime, Name, Buyers, Sellers) VALUES (cast(TIMESTAMP 'NOW' as date), '",InputTime,"', '",Name,"',"Buyers,",", Sellers)")
cur.execute("commit;")
```

Answer (score 1):

if dTime is a datetime entry in python

```
timeforSQL = dTime.strftime("%Y") + "-" + dTime.strftime("%m") + "-" + dTime.strftime("%d") + " " + dTime.strftime("%H") + ":" + dTime.strftime("%M")
```

Which you then enter as a string in your SQL INSERT command. (So remove the cast)

Does it work with ":"? Never tried it - I know it works with "-".